# How can these if/else blocks be improved?

Tags: php, algorithm, logic

I think that there is a mistake in my code logic, because there are two successive elseif blocks withe nearly the same code:

```
//first elseif
elseif (!$socialUser && empty($siteUserId)) {
        //first time user
        $secretWord = $this->RandomString->getRand(7);
        $data = array('User'=> array(
                  'username' => $this->userData['username'],
                  'password' => $this->Auth->password($secretWord),
                  'email' => $this->userData['email'],
                  'name' => $this->userData['name']               
              ));
        $siteUserId = $this->_addSiteUser($data);
        if ($siteUserId){
          $data = array('SocialUser' => array(
            'title' => 'facebook',
            'identifier' => $this->FB_userId,
            'user_id' => $siteUserId
        ));
          if ($this->_addSocialUser($data)){
            $this->Auth->login($siteUserId);
            $l = $this->Session->read('Auth.redirect');
        if (empty($l)) $l = array('controller' => 'qurans', 'action' => 'index');       
        $this->controller->Session->setFlash(__('You are logined using Facebook Sucessfully!'.$this->userData['name'], true).' '.$secretWord, 'done_msg');
        $this->Session->delete('Auth.redirect');        
        $this->controller->redirect($l);
          }
          else{
            $this->controller->Session->setFlash(__('There is an error during adding you as a social member. Contact admin!',true), 'error_msg');
         // $this->controller->redirect($this->Auth->loginAction);
          $this->logout();
          $this->controller->redirect(array('controller' => 'qurans', 'action' => 'index'));

          }
        }

    }
//second elseif
    elseif($socialUser && empty($siteUserId)){
      $secretWord = $this->RandomString->getRand(7);
        $data = array('User'=> array(
                  'username' => $this->userData['username'],
                  'password' => $this->Auth->password($secretWord),
                  'email' => $this->userData['email'],
                  'name' => $this->userData['name']               
              ));
        $siteUserId = $this->_addSiteUser($data);
        if ($siteUserId){
//HERE IS ONLY THE DIFFERENCE
          $data = $socialUser;
          $data['SocialUser']['user_id'] = $siteUserId;
//DIFFERENCE END HERE
          if ($this->_addSocialUser($data)){
            $this->Auth->login($siteUserId);
            $l = $this->Session->read('Auth.redirect');
        if (empty($l)) $l = array('controller' => 'qurans', 'action' => 'index');       
        $this->controller->Session->setFlash(__('You are logined using Facebook Sucessfully!'.$this->userData['name'], true).' '.$secretWord, 'done_msg');
        $this->Session->delete('Auth.redirect');        
        $this->controller->redirect($l);
          }
          else{
            $this->controller->Session->setFlash(__('There is an error during adding you as a social member. Contact admin!',true), 'error_msg');
         // $this->controller->redirect($this->Auth->loginAction);
          $this->logout();
          $this->controller->redirect(array('controller' => 'qurans', 'action' => 'index'));

          }
        }

    }
```

I think the code works fine, but I don't feel good with the copy and paste code block among two successive elseif blocks? Are there any ideas to improve this code? or is it fine?

Comment: Please at least indent the code properly, this is terrifically hard to read.

Comment: @deceze It is copy and paste from netbeans IDE formated code. The most important is the basic idea itself. i.e two successive elseif with almost the same code!

Comment: I don't care where it comes from, it is hard to read and hence hard to give any specific advice. If you want people to analyze your code for mistakes or advice, don't make their heads explode unnecessarily.

Comment: Yes, this is hard to read. I'd not normally downvote this, but if someone who might help you says "Please indent the code", I'd just do it if I wanted some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest your `ifs`

```
...
elseif (empty($siteUserId)) {
    // common code
    if ($socialUser) {
        // social-user specific code
    } else {
        // non-social-user specific code
    }
    // more common code
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create another nested `if-else`:

```
elseif (empty($siteUserId)) {
    ...
    if ($socialUser) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

This way you can separate the code that is common in case `empty($siteUserId)` if `true` and differentiate the rest of it based on the boolean value of `$socialUser`.